# Transformar o {props.produtos.map((produto) =>{} em uma função assincrona

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

Estou fazendo um sistema de carrinho(de loja), onde o usuário clica no botão "adicionar no carrinho", ele adiciona o produto no banco de dados da seguinte maneira: Id_carrinho, Id_user, Id_produto

Na pagina carrinho, é pra visualizar os produtos que ela selecionou

=> carrega os itens do usuário do banco de dados: `select * from carrinho where id_user = "3"` (esse código retorna uma props.produtos)

=> e depois eu passei o props na function ficando assim: `function Carrinho(props){}`

=> e no meu return eu fiz um map do meu produto, para que ele faça uma pesquisa para trazer a informação do produto separado, `select * from produto where id_produto = "produto vindo do map"`, ficando assim:

```
        async function itensDocarrinho(funcao){
                const produbusca = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/product/produto-solto',                 
                 {
                         method: 'POST',
                         body: JSON.stringify({ "idproduto": funcao}),
                         headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
                  });
           const resprod = await produbusca.json();
           console.log(resprod)//ele retorna certinho
        }
        const pesquisarprod = itensDocarrinho(produto.id_produto);
        console.log(pesquisarprod)//ele retorna: Promise { <pending> }
        return(
            <div>
                <div>
                    <Image/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                       <h1>pegar o titulo do produto ak</h1>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
        );
})}
```

Ele me retorna certinho no `console.log(resprod.dataProd)`, agora quando eu trago ele para a const 'pesquisarprod' ele me retorna uma 'Promise {pending}', eu queria que no lugar dessa Promise {pending}, ele me retornasse o respro.dataProd. Eu acredito que para resolver esse problema tenha que transformar o `{props.produtos.map((produto) =>{}` em uma função assincrona, para colocar um `await` no `const pesquisarprod = itensDocarrinho(produto.id_produto);` mas não sei como faço isso

Answer (score 1):

Essa linha de código

```
 const pesquisarprod = itensDocarrinho(produto.id_produto);
```

Deveria ser um handleButtonClick que recebe o id do produto mapeado, executa a função e seta um estado.

```
 const Component = ({ produto }) => {
  const [itensDoCarrinho, setItensDoCarrinho] = useState();

  async function itensDocarrinho(id) {
    const produbusca = await fetch(
      "http://localhost:8080/api/product/produto-solto",
      {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({ idproduto: id }),
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      }
    );
    const resprod = await produbusca.json();
    setItensDoCarrinho(resprod); // ou itensDoCarrinho.push(resprod) se for vários itens
    console.log(resprod); //ele retorna certinho
  }

  const handleSearchProduct = async (id) => {
    await itensDocarrinho(id);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Image />
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <h1 onClick={() => handleSearchProduct(produto.id_produto)}>
            texto qualquer
          </h1>
          <p>Itens: {itensDoCarrinho ? itensDoCarrinho : ""} </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Nesse caso retorna uma Promise porque vc não pegou o resultado dessa chamada assíncrona, tem que fazer um await dentro de um try catch ou um then.

```js
const pesquisarprod = itensDocarrinho(produto.id_produto).then(response => response);
console.log(pesquisarprod)
```

Ou fazendo assim:

```js
try{
 const pesquisarprod = await itensDocarrinho(produto.id_produto)
 console.log(pesquisarprod)
}
catch(err){
 console.log(err)
}
```

Comment: No seu caso o pesquisarprod  é uma promessa, não um resultado certo. Esse itensDocarrinho pode não retornar , então vc tem que esperar a função retornar algum valor para depois utilizá-lo no seu código.

Comment: obg, pela ajuda =)